# Order of printing with printf and my own print

Tags: c, assembly, printf, inline-assembly

In an assignment which I am doing I need to make my own lib which should contain a functions to print string(`prints`), print integer(`printi`) and return the number of characters printed. This library should be written with in-line assembly language (without using any stdio.h libraries)

The problem is everything is working fine but I am not able to understand the order in which `printf`  and `printi` are being called.

Here is my code:

My own myl Library:

```
/* 
 * print_int.c 
 * A system call to print an integer 
 */
#include "myl.h"  // my own library
#define BUFF 20

int printi(int n){  // my own printi function to print numbers
    char buff[BUFF], zero='0';
    int i=0, j, k, bytes;

    // saveN = n;
    if(n == 0) buff[i++]=zero;
    else{
        if(n < 0) {
            buff[i++]='-';
            n = -n;
        }
        while(n){
            int dig = n%10;
            buff[i++] = (char)(zero+dig);
            n /= 10;
        }
        if(buff[0] == '-') j = 1;
        else j = 0;
        k=i-1;
        while(j<k){
            char temp=buff[j];
            buff[j++] = buff[k];
            buff[k--] = temp;
        }
    } 
    // buff[i]='\n';
    bytes = i;

    __asm__ __volatile__ (
      "movl $4, %%eax \n\t"
      "movl $1, %%ebx \n\t"
      "int $128 \n\t"
      :
      :"c"(buff), "d"(bytes)
    ) ;  // $4: write, $1: on stdin

    return bytes;
}


int prints(char *str){  //my own prints function to print strings
    int i;
    for (i = 0; str[i]!='\0'; ++i) {}

  __asm__ __volatile__ (
    "movl $4, %%eax \n\t"
    "movl $1, %%ebx \n\t"
    "int $128 \n\t"
    :
    :"c"(str), "d"(i)
    ) ;  // $4: write, $1: on stdin
    return i;
}
```

and my test.c file :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myl.h"
int main()
{ 
    int n,k;
    char s[100];
    printf("Please enter a string: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%[^\n]",s);
    k=prints(s);
    printf("\nNO of chars printed = ");

    printi(k);  // number of chars printed
    return 0;
}
```

Everything is working fine but k is being printed first before the `NO of chars printed =` gets printed..

This is what the terminal shows:

```
Please enter a string: asdf
asdf
4NO of chars printed =
```

I expect it to be:

```
Please enter a string: asdf
asdf
NO of chars printed =4
```

so whats wrong with the order...?

Comment: Technically `fflush(stdin)` is an undefined operation in C. Some platforms support it as an extension, but it's not portable.

Comment: Generally, using `FILE *` (like `stdout`) and file descriptors (like 1 in your assembler) on the same file is not a good idea. Perhaps replace `printf` by a call to `write`. (Assuming your comment has a typo and is meant to be `// $4: write, $1: on stdout`.)

Comment: Minor: Consider `char buff[sizeof(int)*CHAR_BITS/3 + 3]` to avoid the magic number `20`.

Comment: @chux Sorry, I didn't understand your comment.... :(

Comment: Code uses `#define BUFF 20`.  Why is 20 special?  That on your system, `20` _appears_ to be big enough is a "Magic number":  It appears without justification.  By using a formula such as `sizeof(int)*CHAR_BITS/3 + 3`, the size needed adapts.  Should `int` be a 64-bit integer, `BUFF` will be 24.  if `int` was 16-bit, `BUFF` would be 8.  If `int` was 128 bit, `BUFF` would be `45`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When stdout is a terminal, `printf()` does line-buffering by default. Which means it does not call the actual `write()` system call unless it sees a `\n` character. So your `printi()` prints first, the string gets flushed from the buffer when the program exits.

You should probably use your own non-buffering `prints()`.

Or indeed `fflush(stdout);` immediately after `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `fflush(stdout);` right after your `printf()`. it's possible that the output is being buffered.

Answer (score 0):

The stdout buffer can be disabled calling :

```
setbuf (stdout,NULL);
```

Inserting this at the beginning of your main, allow to mix stdout and your implementation keeping the calling order.